# How to Bind Many items to list view and Show only Few

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

How to Bind 8 items to list view and Show only 4.

My requirement includes binding X items to asp:listview control and show only X/2 items and on click of more show all X items

I cannot get the records again from database nor can use session.

Comment: What have you tried? We won't provide a solution for you unless you try something first. Try searching for "paging".

Answer (score 0):

You can have two lists. One is for showing, and one is your "cached database".

Simply load all 8 items into the full list, and then pick out the ones your are interested in into your "filter list", and have the listview bind to that list instead.